# External usb SSD Restic/Backrest backup automation

Tags: shell-script, python, backup, lxc, restic

I've a zimaboard micro server with proxmox and a debian 10 CT that is delegate for backup system (Restic/Backrest) with an external usb ssd always attached.

It is possible to pilote the external usb ssd hd and switch it on (or mounted) only for a certain period dedicated to backup my files and keep it off (or unmounted) the rest of the time with a bash or python script?